# Storms form above my head

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography, literature

> I have searched for treasure in Egypt,
>   and spent a lifetime fishing in the Atlantic.
>   I have seen powerful storms form above me,
>   and felt the earth shaking with devastating effect.
>   I have seen giant tortoises arrive and disappear.
>   For a thousand years people have travelled to visit me.

What is my name?

Hints:

> The tortoises are actual tortoises.
>
>  The storms are actual storms.

Comment: literature tag... Hmmm...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A name which seems to suit is:

> Santiago

I have searched for treasure in Egypt,

> Santiago from Paulo Coelho's [The Alchemist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Alchemist_(novel)) who travels to the pyramids  looking for treasure.

and spent a lifetime fishing in the Atlantic.

> Santiago, the title character Cuban fisherman of Hemingway's [The Old Man and the Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Old_Man_and_the_Sea).

I have seen powerful storms form above me,

> Santiago is a common place name in the Caribbean affected by hurricanes. Santiago City, Philippines has been hit by typhoons. (I think this answer needs to be more specific here.)

and felt the earth shaking with devastating effect.

> Santiago, Chile, has suffered many devastating earthquakes, the largest being in [1647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1647_Santiago_earthquake).

I have seen giant tortoises arrive and disappear.

> [Santiago Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santiago_Island_(Gal%C3%A1pagos)) in the Galápagos has had, and lost, populations of giant tortoises.

For a thousand years people have travelled to visit me.

> [Santiago de Compostela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santiago_de_Compostela), destination of the Way of St. James, a pilgrimage route since the 9th C.

Comment: This is the intended answer. For the storm clue, there's a certain type of storm named after the place where they are formed.

Answer (score 7):

I have searched for treasure in Egypt,

> Sphynx guards a treasure in pyramids.

and spent a lifetime fishing in the Atlantic.

> [Yes, sphinx has been found underwater in Bahamas](https://www.pinterest.de/pin/265571709253489606/)

I have seen powerful storms form above me, and felt the earth shaking with devastating effect.

> Sphinx has seen a lot of wars. There is a story that her nose was destroyed by a cannonball fired by Napoleon's soldiers.

I have seen giant tortoises arrive and disappear.

> [The giant tortoises are German Zeppelins.](https://goo.gl/images/gtcmsc)

For a thousand years, people have travelled to visit me.

> A lot of tourists come to Giza to see the Sphinx statue.

Comment: Hi, Viktor.  Welcome to PSE! Good answer!  In the future, please hide your answer using the spoiler tag (">!").

Comment: Thank you. I will. Sorry, it was my first answer on the forum.

Comment: No problem, feel free to take a [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour). 
 Happy puzzling!

Comment: never would have gotten that since I was thinking that the tortoises were tectonic plates.

Comment: Hi, @ViktorBober ! It looks like the Bahamas thing is likely a fraud. See [here](http://blog.cnbeyer.com/just-plain-weird/the-plague-of-faux-news-and-i-dont-mean-fox-news/)

Comment: Hi, @Brandon_J ! There are different theories. Check for the name of  Archaeologist Sherif El Morsi for example. But applying the knowledge of school geography I will give you another proof...for example the story of this [French corvette] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_corvette_Sphinx_(1829))

Comment: But the picture isn't even an original picture. It's from the cover of a book from Egyptian photography @ViktorBober  - OK just looked and I like the link as an answer instead of your current one.

Answer (score 3):

Is this

> *water* or possibly the *ocean*?

I have searched for treasure in Egypt,

> The Nile River (composed of water) was quite a treasure to the ancient Egyptians.

and spent a lifetime fishing in the Atlantic.

> The Atlantic Ocean consists primarily of water.

I have seen powerful storms form above me,

> Hurricanes; waterspouts.

and felt the earth shaking with devastating effect.

> Tsunamis are the result of underwater earthquakes and they can be extremely deadly.

I have seen giant tortoises arrive and disappear.

> Maybe because they are thought to have evolved from water creatures, which evolved from something else.

For a thousand years people have traveled to visit me.

> Water is fairly important for life, so before sewer and plumbing systems were invented, humans had to go to the water.

Comment: gonna ruin your 999 rep to a 1009 with a +1 lol ;) hope you don't mind ;)

Comment: Not at all haha